# web2py on a Virtual Machine

Tags: python, web2py

I have a web2py app I developed on my local machine. I tried to move the application to a Windows Server 2003 Virtual Machine but when I run it on the VM the app simply errors out on start up and when I click to see the error it prompts me for the admin password. When I enter it, the app errors again. There are no errors output on the console before, during, or closing the server.

Is there something special I need to do for setup on a VM? Is this some kind of Apache problem? I believe the server only has http protocols active. I am using port 8080, since I think through version control the parameters_8000.py is a password I do not know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Can you share the error details? If you can't access the error dump file via the admin app, use some other tool to view the file under ...web2py/theapp/errors. The file format isn't easily readable, but the last few lines are usually pretty informative.